# C++ Structuring Unit tests for a large project

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I have a very large project that has no unit tests, but I still don't know how to structure it.

What I don't think works well is storing the unit tests in the respective subfolders of the project.

My view is to clone the structure of the project and write the unit tests in it.

For example if I have

```
src/lib/class
```

then I would make a

```
test/lib/class_test
```

I will be working mainly with the Google Test Framework. What do you think? How do you structure your unit tests ? Are there any open source projects that use google tests ? I would be happy to have a look.

Comment: Are there components that can be clearly separated and are tested individually? If this is the case I'd prefer to keep the unit tests close to the code they test (`libA/src`, `libA/include`, `libA/tests`). This makes it easier to keep related parts together. E.g. if `libA` is a git submodule, you most likely want to be able to test the submodule without accessing the parent repo/sibling repos. If this is the best approach in your case is impossible to tell based on the limited info provided though.

Comment: This is definitely an opinion question - so there are lots of right answers and sounds like the way you're planning would be fine. In my experience, if you will have a large team of developers, the closer the unit tests are to the code they're testing, the more likely that someone in the future will keep the tests up to date. I would have a folder `src/lib/class/test` with all the tests that exercise the project code in `src/lib/class/`

Comment: I sometimes struggle with a similar question: Where to put the "public" headers? I prefer to keep them in the directory of the source files but it  makes additional effort for deploy (filtering out everything what's needed to use the lib. in opposition to build the lib.) I've seen separate include folders here and there and considered to change my convention in the future, maybe. This decision is probably done in your case, and I just would follow the existing scheme.